# Configure Websphere not to wrap RuntimeExceptions thrown from Filter.doFilter

Tags: java, websphere

When working with Websphere 7.0, `RuntimeException`s thrown from the `Filter.doFilter` are wrapped in a `ServletException`, instead of being propagated as they are.

Is there any way of configuring Websphere to throw the original exception instead of wrapping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because then the app container wouldn't know how to handle them.

Just use `getCause()` to get the original exception if you have your own error handler.

Comment: Thanks, that is my contingency plan. As this is an existing application - and I'm not sure I found all the places where this assumption is made - I would prefer to ask WAS to do it for me. If that's not possible, I will unwrap the `ServletException` wherever I find a problem.

Comment: WAS won't :-) Just check which kind of exception you get and unwrap it if it's `ServletException`.